# How to make sub category not linkable through magento/admin?

Tags: magento, categories

I am trying to make one of my sub categories unclickable, through magento admin.I am bit new to these kind of tasks and tried to find answer through google and stack overflow, but no luck. Can someone please advice?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your problem in more detials ?

Answer (score 1):

Because your question doesn't provide us with enough information on what exactly you mean unclickable, but i think that is what you ask for.

The first thing that you can do is go to your admin panel, on the navigation bar on the 'Catalog' dropdown and click 'Manage Categories'

Click on the category that you want and then change the field 'Is Active' to 'No'. Doing that will not allow your customers to see this category on your website but you can use it internally for your product management.

Also you if you want more information you can watch this video 
 ["About Magento Categories"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHzOkACdriU)